# Ways to export module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine this code:

```
var authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
...
};
```

Can I export the above code like these?

`module.exports = {authenticate};` or `module.exports = authenticate;`

Can I import above code like these?
`var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');` or `var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate');`

Comment: Yes. `module.exports = authenticate;` => `var authenticate =` and `module.exports = {authenticate};` => `var {authenticate} =`. If you export authenticate, you can import authenticate. If you export an object with authenticate as a method, you have to import the object and extract the method.

Comment: TBF it would have been quicker to test those two code variations yourself than write this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve all your troubles: https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/

exporting value:

autheticate.js

```
module.exports = authenticate;
```

other-file.js

```
const authenticate = require('./autheticate.js')
```

or exporting object

autheticate.js

```
module.exports = {authenticate};
```

other-file.js

```
const {authenticate} = require('./autheticate.js')
```